# How to delete Matrixxd def in Eigen in JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, eigen

Exist the way how can I delete Matrixxd declared? Because when I want to use:

```
     delete
```

This says error in compile

```
        Eigen::Matrix4d' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
    make.exe: ***
```

When I want to use:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jp_algi_CoreC_vector
     (JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jfloatArray input){
jfloat* flt1 ;
jsize size = env->GetArrayLength(input);
jint i;
jint j=0;
jfloat* out ;
Matrix4d C(400,400);

 //compute part

  delete C;
```

And whats the difference between Jdouble and C+ Double? I think there is not one. So the J Datatypes I can use only for the order in the code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Matrix4d C(400,400);` does not make sense: a Matrix4d is a 4x4 matrix, so it cannot be resized to a 400x400 matrix.

Second, the operator `delete` is used to free memory allocated by the operator `new`. In your case the matrix C is created on the stack, and it is C that is responsible to allocate/free the underlying memory.

So assuming you actually want dynamic sized matrices, (i.e., MatrixXd), then you can simply resize it to 0x0 to free the allocated memory:

```
MatrixXd C(400,400);
// ...
C.resize(0,0);
// reuse C later
```

If you don't need C later, you can also use blocks:

```
{
  MatrixXd C(400,400);
  // ...
}
// At this stage C has been automatically deleted.
```